# Codeigniter json_decode view as a variable returns NULL

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Can't seem to find the solution to this, I want to load json data from a view variable like this

```
 $this->json = $this->load->view('/jsonfiles/page.json','',true);
```

Outputting

```
var_dump(json_decode($this->json,true));
```

**= NULL**

The View seems to be rendering the .json file incorrectly, for the json_decode to fail. (maybe not incorrectly, but in a different format), Ive already tried to utf8_encode, no luck

JSON Variable within the page.json

```
[
  {
    "page" : {
      "name" : "PageNameHere",
      "date" : true
    }
  }
]
```

Or is there an alternative to doing this?

**UPDATE**: Yes it works when its an actual string in the variable like this

```
$this->json = '[{"page":{"name":"PageNameHere","date":true}}]';
var_dump(json_decode($this->json,true));
```

**SOLUTION**: So I've decided to figure this out one, and by my mistake, I had a "," comma in the last part of my JSON, which wasn't in this thread, I shorten the JSON for topic, but I found it, using this neat error switch, able to find JSON rendering errors

```
 switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
```

My Issue was labeled as "**Syntax error, malformed JSON**"

Comment: Why do you think `$this->load->view()` should be in JSON format?  [The CodeIgniter docs, simply says  _"...returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser."_](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).  It says nothing about the format of this string.

Comment: @Sparky no, I dont want view() to be json format, I'm using view() to return my file into a string variable, however the json_decode isnt able to read the format, for whatever the damn reason is, need to look this up some more.

Comment: Well, [`json_decode()` only takes a JSON encoded string as it's input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).  If `$this->load->view()` is not giving you a JSON encoded string, then not sure what you expect.

Comment: I've tried this, var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/page.json'),true)); and it still does not work, thats reading a json file directly. What am I missing?

Comment: @Sparky, you can put json encoded urls into a string, and decode them, how do I convert a string already in json format encoded for json decode?

Comment: @Sparky, the string part does not matter however, In my Update 2, I have used a pure string into the json_decode, and worked.

Comment: Apparently, like I said a couple comments ago, `$this->load->view()` is not giving you a JSON encoded string.